# Is this a feasible idea for auto-updates of a CLI through npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, auto-update, conceptual

I'm writing a cli to run on node. I'm going to distribute it using npm. I really like Chrome/Firefox's model of automatic updates.

Would it be a bad idea to simply call the following on startup, or right before the process ends?

```
require('child_process').exec('npm update -g package-name');
```

I honestly don't see why it wouldn't, assuming all users install through `npm i -g package-name`.

PS: thought of asking this in [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) instead, but chose stack overflow. Do let me know if this question is out of place though.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to see a module that updates itself or installs other modules programmatically. IMHO something like that is unexpected behavior and if I found that a module I installed was doing this, I'd promptly uninstall it.